# Real time process list

Tags: time, process, cpu

I'm trying to make a real time process list at python. I want that every 5 seconds the list i made will be updated. Moreover I want to get cpu time usage for each  process but the output is 0 for some reason.... 
This is a part from the code:

```
def start(self):
      while True:
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        processes = []
        for process in self.wmi_object.Win32_Process ():
              size = int(process.WorkingSetSize) / 1024
              try:
                p = psutil.Process(process.ProcessId)
                cpu_percent = 0# p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
                processes.append( process.Name + " " + str(process.ProcessId) + " " +  str(size) + "kb" + " " + str(cpu_percent) )
              except : pass
        self.clientNetwork.send (  pickle.dumps(processes) )
        time.sleep(5)
```

I don't know how to make this a right. Every 5 second the processes just added to the list the previous stay instead of being deleted. 
Appriciate help :)